# AngularJS reversing a list of items shows non-reversed index numbering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wrote a filter to reverse a list using one of the many stack overflow questions about reverse filters.

My code:

```
<div ng-repeat="query in queries | reverse">
  <p>Submission: {{$index}}</p>
  <p>Title: {{query.title}}</p>
  <p>Body: {{query.response}}</p>
</div>
```

The array:

```
var queries = [
  { title: "Query type A", body: "Response of query type A" },
  { title: "Query type B", body: "Response of query type B" },
  { title: "Query type C", body: "Response of query type C" }
];
```

Now that my list is reversed, I'd like to show a count on each item, so it appears like the following:

```
Submission: 3
Title: Query type C
Body: Response of query type C

Submission: 2
Title: Query type B
Body: Response of query type B

Submission: 1
Title: Query type A
Body: Response of query type A
```

but instead, the order is correctly reversed, but the submission numbering (which is simply `$index`, is backwards:

```
Submission: 1
Title: Query type C
Body: Response of query type C

Submission: 2
Title: Query type B
Body: Response of query type B

Submission: 3
Title: Query type A
Body: Response of query type A
```

I realize that somehow this may be correct behavior, but how do I show the reverse that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$index is simply going through the items in the loop. It is not aware of the reversal. You could have an "id" element in queries, such as:

```
var queries = [
  { title: "Query type A", body: "Response of query type A", id:1 },
  { title: "Query type B", body: "Response of query type B", id:2 },
  { title: "Query type C", body: "Response of query type C", id:3 }
];
```

and use `<p>Submission: {{query.id}}</p>` instead of `<p>Submission: {{$index}}</p>`.

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'd like to not have to set that property within the data object itself, because these objects are the results of actual query field submissions... so the objects will be dynamically added to the list every time a query is run.

Comment: interesting, i just tried printing some subtraction and that appears to have worked, too.

Comment: The subtraction will work for reversing but if you ever decide to sort them in a different order, say by title, then it will break again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the `$index`, printing the difference of the `$index` from the array length works:

`{{queries.length - $index}}`

Answer (score 0):

Its a Good question friend, in past i met the same problem 
Instead of giving the {{$index}}, Give

{{queries.length + 1 - $index}}